# useradd cannot execute / not owner error

Tags: solaris, useradd

I have Solaris 9.

When running useradd as root i have this error.

```
#/usr/sbin/useradd
ksh: /usr/sbin/useradd : cannot exceute
```

Then tried change shell csh and sh but to no avail. csh:

```
# /usr/sbin/useradd : not owner

#ls -l /usr/sbin/useradd
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root    sys      34596 Mar  1  2011 useradd
```

Your expertise will be helpful :)

Comment: what is the output of "file /usr/sbin/useradd"?

Comment: i got an error.
cannot open: Permission denied

Comment: output of your id command? It does not makes much sense

Comment: uid=0 (root)  gid=1(other) groups=0 (root),2(bin),3(sys),4(adm),5(uucp),6(mail),7(tty),8(lp)9,(nuucp),12(daemon)

Comment: yeah this is so weird

Comment: What does `ldd /usr/sbin/useradd` return?  And another binary in `/usr/sbin`

Comment: The same error. It seems any commands doesnt work.

cannot open: Permission denied

Comment: would have someone messed up dir permissions? ls -la /usr | grep sbin please.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   8 root    bin           7168 May 13  2012 sbin

Answer (score 0):

Suspecting the file may be corrupt.
Do you have another similarly configured/patched box to compare?

If not, it should be part of SUNWcsu.  To verify that and pkg:

`solaris10 [17] grep useradd /var/sadm/install/contents
/usr/sbin/roleadd=../../usr/sbin/useradd l none SUNWcsu
/usr/sbin/useradd f none 0555 root sys 40304 49661 1343868237 SUNWcsu
/usr/share/man/man1m/useradd.1m f none 0644 root root 11879 27402 1352766995 SUNWman`
solaris10 [18] `pkginfo SUNWcsu
system      SUNWcsu Core Solaris, (Usr)`

`pkgchk SUNWcsu`   <-- to check pkg